# Cyper clojure necons tquery: How to Match by Label with {_variable}?

Tags: clojure, neo4j, cypher

I am trying to use clojure neocons to perform a cypher query where I need to use a variable placeholder for the label:

```
(def node-query "MATCH (n:{_nodetype})
                 RETURN n;")
```

I am getting an error when I add {_nodetype} but no error when I remove {_nodetype}

```
"Invalid input '{': expected whitespace or a label name (line 1, column 10 (offset: 9))\\n\\\"MATCH (n:{_nodetype})\\\"\\n ^\",\n \"exception\"...
```

Here is my call to tquery:

```
(cy/tquery conn node-query {:_nodeid _nodeid :_nodetype "Folder"})
```

What is the cypher / neocons syntax to MATCH by label with a variable?

I am very grateful for help you could suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot parameterize a label (or a relationship type). The rationale for this is that a different parameter value might result in a completely different query plan. Internally the query plan is cached with the query string.

For now just do string concatenation in Clojure to have "semi-dynamic" labels or relationship types.

Comment: More on cypher parameters is dcoumented [here](http://neo4j.com/docs/2.2.6/cypher-parameters.html)